# How to create texture using raw RGBA texture data without having to use LockRect

Tags: directx, directx9

I was previously uploading textures to DirectX by creating texture in `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` and then calling `LockRect` to upload the texture data to DirectX.  However, I have switched to using DirectX9 Ex, and can no longer use `D3DPOOL_MANAGED`, so in order to call `LockRect` I have to make the texture use `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC`.  However, I would prefer not to have to use `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC`.  Is my only other option to create a texture in system memory, and then call `IDirect3DDevice9::UpdateTexture` to get the texture data into video memory?  I also see there is a `D3DXFillTexture` function.  But what i really want is something equivalent to `glTexImage2D` where i can create a texture and pass it raw data.

Note that I have stripped down RGBA texture data, otherwise I would try using `DXCreateTextureFromFileInMemory`.

Answer (score 1):

Other alternatives include using UpdateTexture or UpdateSurface from a D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM source.

Under Vista+ (which I assume you're targetting since you're using 9Ex) you can supply the texture data via the pSharedHandle arg to CreateTexture; per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> In Windows Vista CreateTexture can create a texture from a system memory pointer allowing the application more flexibility over the use, allocation and deletion of the system memory.

Caveat: I haven't done this and can't vouch for it.

Comment: Per the documentation you cite, textures allocated with `CreateTexture` must be allocated in `D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM`. Which makes sense, cause the `CreateTexture` function is designed to create DX9 texture handles that are shareable between processes. But because the texture isn't put in device memory as in the cases of `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` or previously `D3DPOOL_MANAGED` this isn't going to be a good plan.

Comment: When I tried `LockRect` I get an HRESULT of `D3DERR_INVALIDCALL` when I don't use `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC`, which was the point of my post...I don't want to use `D3DUSAGE_DYNAMIC`.  Do you know of a magic way around this?

Comment: Also, I agree with @Jonathan Mee above. The `CreateTexture` with a shared resource has to be created in the system memory. What I was really looking for is to be able to create `D3DPOOL_DEFAULT` texture without having to go through a `D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM` texture. It is a nice tip though, since it could be a little simpler than `LockedRect`